# Error in developing the 3D CNN model for human body recognition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am facing an error while loading the 3DCNN model and it shows kernel size is missing one attribute.

Code:

```
# number of convolutional filters to use at each layer
nb_filters = [32, 32]

# level of pooling to perform at each layer (POOL x POOL)
nb_pool = [3, 3]

# level of convolution to perform at each layer (CONV x CONV)
nb_conv = [5,5]

# Pre-processing
train_set = train_set.astype('float32')
train_set -= np.mean(train_set)
train_set /=np.max(train_set)

# Define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution3D(nb_filters[0],nb_depth=nb_conv[0], nb_row=nb_conv[0], nb_col=nb_conv[0], input_shape=(1, img_rows, img_cols, patch_size), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0], nb_pool[0])))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes,init='normal'))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kernel_size'
```

Comment: Please, add the lines with the `import` statements so we know which modules are you using (Keras?). Also, in which line of your code is the error happening?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hi @mohammad Nadeem Ahangar, as the error says, the "kernel_size" argument is missing. Please add it to the Convolution3D layer and let us know if the issue still persists. We could help you better if you provided more information, such as the "Keras" version. Thank you!